# Is it possible to have a Gson constructor that runs after the attributes get their value?

Tags: java, gson

Is it somehow possible to enable / write a constructor for a class that would run after that class' attributes receive their value from Gson.fromJson() method? So that I can calculate some attributes value that derive from the ones that have been deserialized? For example:

ps: For some reason my constructor always runs first, before my two other attribues would have their values.

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String fullName;

    Person() {
        fullName = firstName + fullName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors must run before everything else, your object (i.e. an instance of your class) just doesn't exist prior to the constructor being run.
You could achieve the first/last name composition like this :

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    if(lastName != null) {
        fullName = firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    if(firstName != null) {
        fullName = firstName + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I was curious because if I remember correctly in C# the serializer that can be found in .NET actually fills up the attributes first and only after that is the constructor run.